# mysql join function not joining

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

here i have two tables names rooms and student_hostel as follows.
rooms look like this

```
    id rm_number  capacity    bed_no               class    hostel  is_vaccant
    40    1         5       1A,1B,1C,1D,1E          27        7     1
    41    2         4       2A,2B,2C,2D             28        7     0
    42    3         3       3A,3B,3C                29        10    1
    43    4         4       4A,4B,4C,4D             30        10    1
    44    5         6       5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F       27        7     1
    45    6         7       6A,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G    29        10    1
```

my student_hostel table looks like this

```
     id     first_name     stud_id    hostel   class    room    bed     status
    175     siraj         WPGH00175     7      28        41      2A     P
    176     nesru         WPGH00176     7      28        41      2B     P
    177     faizal        WPGH00177     7      28        41      2C     P
    179     mashoor       WPGH00179     7      28        41      2D     G
```

when i use my code like this

```
public function view_room_status($num,$offset)
{   
        $this->db->select('rooms.*,class.name as class_name,hostel.name as hostel_name,student_hostel.status');
        $this->db->join('class','class.id=rooms.class');
        $this->db->join('hostel','hostel.id=rooms.hostel');

        $this->db->join('student_hostel','rooms.id=student_hostel.room');
        $query=$this->db->get('rooms',$num,$offset)->result();
        return $query;
}
```

iam getting like this

```
  sl no     room     class          hostel          Bed
   1         2      Periyar2        Periyar     2A 2B 2C 2D
   2         2      Periyar2        Periyar     2A 2B 2C 2D
   3         2      Periyar2        Periyar     2A 2B 2C 2D
   4         2      Periyar2        Periyar
```

but i want to get like this

```
    sl no   room    class         hostel             Bed
     1       1     Periyar1     Periyar     1A,1B,1C,1D,1E
     2       2     Periyar2     Periyar     2A,2B,2C,2D
     3       3     Pamba1       Pamba       3A,3B,3C
     4       4     Pamba2       Pamba       4A,4B,4C,4D
     5       5     Periyar1     Periyar     5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F
     6       6     Pamba1       Pamba       6A,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F,6G
```

this is my class table

```
id  name          daily_rent    mon_rent    
11  reservation     200         3000    
27  periyar1        100         3000    
28  periyar2        100         3000 
29  pamba1          100         3000    
30  pamba2          100         3000
```

this is my hostel table

```
id  user_id     name    type    place   address           username  password
7   78         periyar  Girls   tirur   malappuram       periyar    periyarhostel
10  81          pamba   Boys    tirur   malappuram       pamba           pambahostel
```

after getting like this the thing is i want to show all bed occupied by the status 'P' as in one color and all bed occupied by status 'G' in one color

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the problem seems to be with your data. Look at your `student_hostel.room` column: it holds nothing but the value 41, so each row in that table will be matched against room ID 41. As proof, notice that the output of your query has room #2 (ie. ID 41) in every result.

Now I don't have access to all your data (there seems to be a `class` column I cannot see anywhere and a `hostel` one with a string instead of a number) so I would need more information to determine how to properly make the join.

Comment: i had added two other tables

Answer (score 0):

Try using left join it will take all columns from left table and matching from right

Answer (score 0):

You've got one too many joins To get the "Result you want" with the data you are using!

Your tables are definitely joining and doing exactly what you have told them too based upon the data you have provided...

So to get "Your desired Output" based upon what you have provided, Your SQL needs to be

```
SELECT rooms.rm_number,class.name,hostel.username,rooms.bed_no
    FROM rooms
    JOIN class ON class.id=rooms.class
    JOIN hostel ON hostel.id=rooms.hostel
```

And I am guessing your SL No is something you are generating in your table view.

I realize you are doing a Get just about everything query and filtering it in your table view, but that isn't going to work for you in this instance.

Of course this won't get you the room status which you want to use to colorize the rows in the table, so see what SolarBear answered above.